# Shorthand block syntax for factory_girl traits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Is it possible to use the shorthand block syntax for [factory_girl](https://rubygems.org/gems/factory_girl) traits?

Consider this factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    name "name"

    # not using the block shorthand {} syntax, instead using do...end block syntax
    trait :my_name do
      name "Neil"
    end

  end
end
```

And using this factory works:

```
create(:foo, traits: [:my_name])
```

However I would like to use the shorthand block syntax for my traits like so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    name "name"

    # using shorthand block syntax but does not work
    trait :my_name {name "Neil"}

  end
end
```

And now using this factory errors out.  Here is what happens:

```
create(:foo, traits: [:my_name])
```

> syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

This seems odd because I thought that wherever you use `do ... end` you can opt for the shorthand `{}` block syntax.

**Question**:  Is there something wrong with my shorthand block syntax for the factory_girl `trait` method and that is why it is erroring out?  Or: are you just not allowed to use the shorthand block syntax with factory_girl `traits`?  Is there a way to make using the shorthand block syntax for factory_girl traits work?

[Docs on the factory_girl trait attribute](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/4.7.0/FactoryGirl/Trait)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see, `trait` is actually a method that takes a name of the trait and a block. These are 2 parameters of a method. When you used `do ... end` syntax, Ruby interpreter could guess that you are giving a second (block) argument. But, in the second `{ ... }` case, it is not clear, because you might be passing a `Hash` for example.

That's why you need to make it clear that you are passing in the second param and it is a block like this:

```
trait(:my_name) { name "Neil" }
```

Comment: Oh wow!  Awesome thanks!  Looks like I need to study up more on blocks.  Appreciate it!